# Java azure function not deploying dependencies

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

My app has a few maven dependencies. I am able to run the app locally as expected.

When deployed via `mvn clean package` followed by `mvn azure-functions:deploy`, it gets deployed. But when accessed, the function throws an exception.

Though when I deploy it via the `IntelliJ plugin`, it works as expected. What could be going wrong here?

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jp</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>XXXXX</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.14.1</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.4.2</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>XXXXX</functionAppName>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-analytics-synapse-spark</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-synapse</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version> <!-- {x-version-update;com.azure:azure-core;dependency} -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- function app name -->
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <!-- function app resource group -->
                    <resourceGroup>XXXXX</resourceGroup>
                    <!-- function app service plan name -->
                    <appServicePlanName>XXXXX</appServicePlanName>
                    <!-- function app region-->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                    <region>eastus</region>
                    <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                    <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                    <!-- Whether to disable application insights, default is false -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details for all valid configurations for application insights-->
                    <!-- <disableAppInsights></disableAppInsights> -->
                    <runtime>
                        <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>8</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~3</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect.<init>(HttpClientConnect.java:83)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.create(HttpClient.java:393)
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.build(NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.java:94)
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.createInstance(NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.java:18)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:67)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:50)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:40)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:73)
    at com.azure.analytics.synapse.spark.SparkClientBuilder.createHttpPipeline(SparkClientBuilder.java:274)
    at com.azure.analytics.synapse.spark.SparkClientBuilder.buildInnerClient(SparkClientBuilder.java:240)
    at com.azure.analytics.synapse.spark.SparkClientBuilder.buildSparkBatchClient(SparkClientBuilder.java:302)
    at com.microsoft.aiops.orchestrator.SubmitJob.run(SubmitJob.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(JavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:57)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the culprit:https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/381

This issue is only with Java8.

Setting the flag `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_JAVA_LOAD_APP_LIBS` to `True` fixed it in the `Configuration` tab. (you can check [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/java-logging-azure-functions/#deploy-the-azure-function) to know on how to set it)